# unable to set uploaded image path as a url in ckeditor in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm trying to upload image through drag drop in ckeditor

```
<ckeditor
  (ready)="onReady($event)"
  [editor]="editor"
  [(ngModel)]="html" #myckeditor
></ckeditor>

<button (click)="getContent()">click</button>
```

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MyUploadAdapter } from "./myUploadAdapter";
import * as DecoupledEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document";
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk'; 
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public editor: any;
  public html: string;
  @ViewChild('ckeditor') public ckeditor: any;
   private s3: AWS.S3;
  public imageUrl = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');

  constructor() {
    this.editor = DecoupledEditor;
    this.html = "";
    this.s3 = new AWS.S3(); 
  }

  public onReady(editor:any) {
    editor.plugins.get("FileRepository").createUploadAdapter = (loader:any) => {
      let file =   new MyUploadAdapter(loader);
      console.log("file",file)
      return file
    };
    editor.ui
      .getEditableElement()
      .parentElement.insertBefore(
        editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
        editor.ui.getEditableElement()
      );
  }

  public ngOnInit() {

  }
  getContent()
  {
    console.log(this.html)
  }
}
```

myUploadAdapter.ts

```
  upload() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      this.loader.file.then((file:any) => {
      this.uploadImageToS3(file,'img').then(x=>{
        resolve(x)
        console.log(x)
      })

      });
    });
  }

     uploadImageToS3(file: File, folderName: string): Promise<string> {
        console.log("file from sourvce",file)
        const params:.....
        return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
          this.s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
            } else {
              this.imageUrl.next(data.Location);
              resolve(data.Location); // Retrieve the URL of the uploaded image
            }
          });
        });
      }
```

Image files are being uploaded on drag drop but the issue is the when i upload other files the content are being replaced, Any solution to append the uploaded content in the ckeditor and image url should not be base64 i want url in ckeditor.

Thanks